# Why do i need to call dispatch twice when using redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

here is the code while using useDisplatch hook

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchUsers());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

and here is fetchUsers()

```
export const fetchUsers = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchUserRequest());
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => {
        const users = response.data;
        dispatch(fetchUserSuccess(users));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorMsg = error.message;
        dispatch(fetchUserFailure(errorMsg));
      });
  };
};
```

Reason i am writing dispatch twice